# Using a structure as a command line argument in clap

Tags: rust, clap

Trying to use a struct within a struct in `clap`:

```rust
use clap::{Args, Parser};
use std::path::PathBuf;

#[derive(Parser, Debug)]
enum Command {
    Foo(Foo),
}

#[derive(Args, Debug)]
struct Foo {
    bar: Option<Bar>,

    path: PathBuf,
}

#[derive(Parser, Clone, Debug)]
struct Bar {
    bla: u8,

    bla_2: String,
}

fn main() {
    let cli = Command::parse();
    println!("cli {:#?}", cli);
}
```

So I could call the app with the following options: `cargo run -- foo bar 42 baz /tmp/a` or just `cargo run -- foo /tmp/a` since the `bar` argument is optional.

However, currently it does not build:

```
  --> src/main.rs:11:5
   |
11 |     bar: Option<Bar>,
   |     ^^^ the trait `FromStr` is not implemented for `Bar`
   |
```

And since the values within `Bar` have to be space-separated implementing a `FromStr` would not do the trick anyway.

Is it even possible to do something of this fashion in `clap` currently?

Comment: Are the two invocations fixed in your requirements? Because they don't really fit the style of clap, or most command line argument guidelines in general.

Comment: Yeah I the whole purpose is compatibility, otherwise i guess i could just have two normal optional arguments where one requires the other

Comment: In clap, you **cannot** have an optional positional argument in front of a required positional argument. The parser just doesn't work that way, it wouldn't know if `bar` is the optional or the `path`. I think if compatibility really is a requirement, the only choice you have is to parse manually. I'll think about it some more, though, give me a second

Comment: I don't understand your invocation. Are `foo` and `bar` values or a subcommands? If `foo` is the only possibility for the first argument, why have it in the first place?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several problems with your code. The biggest one is:

- An optional positional item can never come **before** a required positional argument

This is a problem in your case because your command line looks like this:

```
cargo run -- <required> [optional] /tmp/a
```

If you have a required path at the end, there **can not** be an optional positional argument before that.

Further problems:

- `#[derive(Parser)]` should be attached to a `struct`, not an `enum`.
- There should only be one `#[derive(Parser)]`, which represents the entry object of your arguments parser.

I'm unsure how else to help you, except pointing out your problems. If the invocations `cargo run -- foo bar 42 baz /tmp/a` and `cargo run -- foo /tmp/a` are non-negotiable, I don't think `clap` is the right library for you; I think you should parse by hand.

Comment: Note that you can always fake it by telling clap that the _second_ argument is optional, then doing something like: `let optional, required = match args.arg2 { Some (required) => (Some (args.arg1), args.arg2), None => (None, args.arg1), };`

Comment: @Jmb sure, but then the --help will be incorrect, and you basically read arguments from an array. Which would give you no benefit over reading the args vector directly.

Comment: It would be good to add an example.